# How to export example.py --help to pdf that the -- does not end up a \ndash in the LaTeX file?

Tags: emacs, escaping, export, latex, org-mode

I have some source code like example.py --help that i want to fit into a heading and export to pdf.

Unfortunately org-mode exports --help to LaTeX without escaping so I end up with an equivalent to \ndash{}help, a long dash and not to separate dashes.

I tried to escape the dashes --help which ended up like spaces in the LaTeX file and therefor as well in the pdf.

I tried to write {-}{-}help which would give me --help in the pdf and not the ligature of two dashes (long dash). But when I export {-}{-}help from org-mode, the braces will be escaped to {-}{-}help in the LaTeX export, which leads to {-}{-}help in the pdf.

I tried then to write {-}{-}help which let to {-}{-}help in the LaTeX code, hence the pdf output is {-}{-}help.

Has anyone a clue how to escape -- from org-mode the correct way?

I suceeded, but ended up with a really ugly solution:

```
**** example.py
     #+BEGIN_LATEX
     {-}{-}help
     #+END_LATEX

     - foo
     - bar
```

The answer was found here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html#Quoting-LaTeX-code

The answer from fniessen is far more practical since it does not blow up the org-file:

```
**** =example.py --help=
- foo
- bar
```

should do it. Or the version with ~ instead of =.

Comment: I suceeded, but ended up with a really ugly solution: http://dpaste.com/1489230/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally,

```
=example.py --help=
```

should do it. Or the version with ~ instead of =.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution is far more practical, then the one i came up.